# RaphaelJS browser incompatibility with text positioning

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, raphael

Im using RaphaelJS to draw images cross browser to fix some compatibility issues.

I was testing on IE8 (Because it doesnt support SVG) then when i finished i test it out on IE9+ and Chrome, and what i got was a miss positioning of the texts. While IE8 the text was perfectly positioned, in the other browsers it all fell apart, so i try to change the value of the position putting as string or with 'px' after like:

```
paper.text("0px", "110px", "Text1").attr({ "fill": "#000099", "font-size": 15, "text-anchor": "start", "font-weight": "bold" });
```

when i did that, it worked again with the most recent browsers but it stopped completly with IE8 (Not even showing the text)

And when i leave like

```
paper.text(0, 110, "Text1").attr({ "fill": "#000099", "font-size": 15, "text-anchor": "start", "font-weight": "bold" });
```

the position get all mess up in the most recent browsers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it`s a known bug, and what happens is that in newer browsers the 'y' Axis need to be half, in the example i had to make a method do identify the browser and divide the y axis value in half.